# how to get value of energy from inbuilt function graycoprops()

Tags: matlab

how to fetch value of energy from the code given below

```
g=rgb2gray(im);
g=double(g);
stats = graycoprops(g, {'energy'});
disp(stats)
```

it shows result like this

```
 Energy: 1.4492e-005
```

but i want only  1.4492e-005

so that i can store it into a file OR
is there any way to store stats variable i.e 'Energy: 1.4492e-005'
into file. i tried this one

```
stats = graycoprops(g, {'energy'});
  fprintf(fwener,'%s',stats);
```

it gives me error  "??? Undefined function or variable 'fwener'."

Answer (score 0):

`stats` is a structure.

```
stats.Energy
```

should give you the number you want to save in a file.

Answer (score 0):

As Molly said, `stats` is structure. If you do this

```
disp(stats)   
disp('List of variables');
whos
disp('List of fields');
fieldnames(stats)
```

you will see this:

```
Energy: 3.7247e-006
List of variables
  Name         Size                 Bytes  Class     Attributes
  ans          1x1                    124  cell                
  g          450x600              2160000  double              
  im         450x600x3             810000  uint8               
  stats        1x1                    184  struct              
List of fields
ans = 
    'Energy'
```

So you should check little deeper what MatLab says.

Have fun ;o)